# Complex? MySQL Query

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the columns, id, date, estValue & gradeid. Each grade id has about 12 records and there are approximately 10 different grades for a total of about 120 records [give or take]  I need to create a selection from the database that gives me a result set that looks something like this:

```
date    |gradeid1 |gradeid2 |gradeid3 3|etc...
01/01/01|estValue1|estValue2||estValue3|etc....
01/01/02|estValue1|estValue2||estValue3|etc....
```

I have a query that can select ONE record, but I need them all ordered by date:

```
select eh.id, eh.date as wdate,
    (select estValue from nas_estimatehistory where `date` like '2011-03-%' and gradeid = '1') as '1',
    (select estValue from nas_estimatehistory where `date` like '2011-03-%' and gradeid = '2') as '2',
    (select estValue from nas_estimatehistory where `date` like '2011-03-%' and gradeid = '3') as '3',
    (select estValue from nas_estimatehistory where `date` like '2011-03-%' and gradeid = '4') as '4',
    (select estValue from nas_estimatehistory where `date` like '2011-03-%' and gradeid = '5') as '5',
    (select estValue from nas_estimatehistory where `date` like '2011-03-%' and gradeid = '6') as '6',
    (select estValue from nas_estimatehistory where `date` like '2011-03-%' and gradeid = '7') as '7',
    (select estValue from nas_estimatehistory where `date` like '2011-03-%' and gradeid = '8') as '8',
    (select estValue from nas_estimatehistory where `date` like '2011-03-%' and gradeid = '9') as '9',
    (select estValue from nas_estimatehistory where `date` like '2011-03-%' and gradeid = '10') as '10'
from nas_estimatehistory eh  
group by wdate 
order by `wdate` asc
limit 1;
```

which returns pretty much what I need, but only 1 row, if I remove the limit, then I get a row for each month [12 rows] but all the column values are the same [they should all be different] i.e. estValue in each row AND column should be a unique value...

I'm not sure what the best way to go about this is.

-thanks
-sean

Comment: Table schema (creation statements) and sample data (presented as SQL `INSERT` statements) are very useful in questions such as this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cross-tabulation](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/wizard/index.html) is the key: use an [aggregate function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html) and the `IF` function.

```
SELECT eh.date AS wdate,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(gradeid=1,estValue,NULL)) as `1`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(gradeid=2,estValue,NULL)) as `2`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(gradeid=3,estValue,NULL)) as `3`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(gradeid=4,estValue,NULL)) as `4`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(gradeid=5,estValue,NULL)) as `5`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(gradeid=6,estValue,NULL)) as `6`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(gradeid=7,estValue,NULL)) as `7`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(gradeid=8,estValue,NULL)) as `8`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(gradeid=9,estValue,NULL)) as `9`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(gradeid=10,estValue,NULL)) as `10`
FROM nas_estimatehistory eh  
GROUP BY wdate 
ORDER BY `wdate` ASC;
```

`MAX` or `MIN` may also be suitable aggregate functions.

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for, is cross tabulation something that is documented in the MySQL docs, - or is it more of a theory type approach [may as well learn something while I'm at it!]

Comment: Interesting, it returns the values as blob objects, - I have to convert them to strings in order for coldfusion to see them properly, is there away to do that in the query itself?

Comment: @Sean: `GROUP_CONCAT` should return a `BLOB` only if `estValue` is a binary string (making the type of the `IF()` expression a binary string); changing `estValue` to a non-binary text type should take care of this. See the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) for more. Another option is to switch to `MAX` or `MIN`, as mentioned above.

Comment: ... You can use [`CONVERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert) or [`CAST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) to cast data from one type to another, but it shouldn't be necessary here.

Answer (score 1):

```
select eh.id, wdate,
    (select estValue from nas_estimatehistory where `date` like `pattern` and gradeid = '1') as '1',
    (select estValue from nas_estimatehistory where `date` like `pattern` and gradeid = '2') as '2',
    (select estValue from nas_estimatehistory where `date` like `pattern` and gradeid = '3') as '3',
    (select estValue from nas_estimatehistory where `date` like `pattern` and gradeid = '4') as '4',
    (select estValue from nas_estimatehistory where `date` like `pattern` and gradeid = '5') as '5',
    (select estValue from nas_estimatehistory where `date` like `pattern` and gradeid = '6') as '6',
    (select estValue from nas_estimatehistory where `date` like `pattern` and gradeid = '7') as '7',
    (select estValue from nas_estimatehistory where `date` like `pattern` and gradeid = '8') as '8',
    (select estValue from nas_estimatehistory where `date` like `pattern` and gradeid = '9') as '9',
    (select estValue from nas_estimatehistory where `date` like `pattern` and gradeid = '10') as '10'
from (
    select eh.*, date_format(eh.date, '%Y-%m') wdate,
                 concat(date_format(eh.date, '%Y-%m'),'-%') `pattern`
    from nas_estimatehistory) eh
group by wdate
order by wdate asc;
```

Comment: this also works well [small correction needed: from nas_estimatehistory eh) eh ], easier for me to understand than outis's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Like I said, forget the group part. It has no effect.
I think I see your problem.

Replace gradeid = '1' with gradeid = eh.gradeid

Comment: hmm. I need each row to be 1 month, each gradeid has 1 value for each month....  I'm not sure what you are trying to tell me.